# What should I do if I get multiple PhD offers?

Tags: phd, application

I have spread my Ph.D. inquiry to several places, varying from low-rank to high-rank universities (for me, high rank is <100 and low rank is >500). I expected to get admission in the Winter semester because I started the inquiry so late when the Fall admission was over. I got four positive replies, including:

- I got replies from two professors from two high-rank universities, which are my priority. They genuinely wanted to accept me in Winter (Spring) semester, but they were unclear about the funding situation for the Winter semester, and they said to respond to me later.
- I got replies from two other professors from two low-rank universities. They were so enthusiastic and wanted me immediately in the Fall semester. However, they are only my plan B if my better options fail.

I want to wait for professors from high-rank universities, but it means that I have to make the other professors wait for me. The problem is that all four above professors know each other very well and collaborate quite often. It will be very awkward for me if I make the professors in low-rank universities wait for me, and in the end, choose a professor who is their collaborator and reject their offers.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: "It will be very awkward for me if I make the professors in low-rank universities wait for me, and in the end, choose a professor who is their collaborator and reject their offers." No, not really. Even if that were the case, which it isn't, what do you want to prioritize: your career or not feeling awkward for a short period of time? (Of course, ranking isn't everything, but that's a different question.)

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, this boils down to individual circumstances and is hard to answer. In German, there is a proverb: "a sparrow in your hand is more valuable than a dove on the roof", meaning it is often better to settle for the secure but (seemingly) inferior option (sparrow) instead of for the better, but less secure option (dove). Yours seems like a similar situation.

The question you should ask yourself is if the (perceived) advantage of going to the top school really translates to better chances afterwards. Maybe you have the possibility to ask senior academicians in your field about it.